# Lookup of a number in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I wanted to ask what am I doing wrong that is causing the if statement to be false every time I run the program. I've also tried to use `.equals(num)` instead of the `Array.asList(num)` to check if the value is in there, but that caused the for loop to repeat the "Not in database" multiple times.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.asList(Data)` creates a list whose only element is an array of int (i.e. `List<int[]>`). That's why `Arrays.asList(Data).contains(num))` always returns false.

Try changing your array to :

```
Integer Data[] = new Integer[n];
```

This will make `Arrays.asList(Data)` create a list of `Integer` (`List<Integer>`) containing all the integers of the original array, which is what you need.

The reason for this behavior is the `Arrays.asList` expects one or more `Object`s as its input. If you pass an array of `Object`s (such as `Integer[]`), it is equivalent to passing multiple `Object`s. If, however, you pass an array of primitives (such as `int[]`), the only `Object` in your input is the array itself, so `Arrays.asList()` creates a list whose only element is that array.

Comment: I spent literally 3+ hours trying to figure out why. I didn't know that I had change the array from int to Integer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Joseph You're welcome. You only have to change your array from int to Integer in order for `Arrays.asList` to behave as you expect. You could have avoided all that trouble if you simply read the input directly into an ArrayList instead of into an array.