# issue with Arrays.asList()

Tags: java

I have a very simple program and I just need to check an array for a value in it.
I have a class called bulkBean. this is it.

```
public class bulkBean {
   private int installmentNo;
   private double amount;

    public int getInstallmentNo() {
        return installmentNo;
    }

    public void setInstallmentNo(int installmentNo) {
        this.installmentNo = installmentNo;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

}
```

Now I have an array of this bulkBean type in my program, this is my program.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test {

    public static boolean scan_bulkList(bulkBean[] bulkList, int i) {

        int[] arr = new int[bulkList.length];

        for(int x=0;x<bulkList.length;x++){
            arr[x] = bulkList[x].getInstallmentNo();
        }

        for(int j = 0; j< arr.length ;j++){

            System.out.println("INFO: array "+j+" = "+arr[j]);

        }

        if (Arrays.asList(arr).contains(i) == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] arg){

        bulkBean bb1 = new bulkBean();
        bb1.setInstallmentNo(1);
        bb1.setAmount(5500);

        bulkBean bb2 = new bulkBean();
        bb2.setInstallmentNo(2);
        bb2.setAmount(4520);

        bulkBean[] bulkArray = new bulkBean[2];
        bulkArray[0] = bb1;
        bulkArray[1] = bb2;

        boolean a = scan_bulkList(bulkArray,1);
        System.out.println("val = "+a);

    }
}
```

I create 2 instances of bulk bean and I set values to them. Then I added those two instances to an array. Then I pass that array to the method to check for a value(also given as a parameter. In this case it is 1.). If the array contains that value, it should return true, otherwise false. 
whatever value I enter, it return false.
Why do I get this issue?

Comment: You know, you could just return `Arrays.asList(arr).contains(i)`.

Comment: Please sopln(Arrays.asList(arr)) and check whether you get proper list or not and follow @Alexander_Winter suggestion.

Comment: @Alexander_Winter - It won't work.

Comment: Change `int[] arr = new int[bulkList.length];` to `Integer[] arr = new Integer[bulkList.length];`.

Comment: A similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333486/lookup-of-a-number-in-an-array/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As TheListMind told, `Arrays.asList()` taken on an `int[]` gives you a list containing the array.

Personally, I would construct directly the List instead of constructing the array, or even better (no need of array instanciation), test while iterating the bulk array :

```
for(int x=0;x<bulkList.length;x++){
    if (bulkList[x].getInstallmentNo() == i){
         return true;     
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: thanks this is correct if you edit it like this. `bulkList[i].getInstallmentNo() == i` to `bulkList[x].getInstallmentNo() == i`. any way thanks

Comment: Written to quickly is often bad. Thanks to overline it

Answer (score 4):

`Arrays.asList()` returns a List which has a single element - an array. So, you are actually comparing *against an array*. You need to compare against each value in the array.

Comment: Arrays.asList(arr) he is passing arr={1,24,54,23,456} not single value. It will convert this array into List [1,24,54,23,456]

Comment: @ShoaibChikate - The list contains only one element i.e, the array. Check the size of the list.

Comment: +1 Agreed. I think changing `int[] arr = new int[bulkList.length];` to `Integer[] arr = new Integer[bulkList.length];` would make the list containing `Integer`s instead of an `int[]` array.

Comment: @TheLostMind I did not get what you said

Comment: @Eng.Fouad - That should have been an answer :P

Comment: @user3892439 - Arrays.asList() is returning a list with only one element. The element is the array of elements. i.e, the list doesn;t contain the elements of the array. The list contains the array. Use,  *Eng.Fouad*'s comment and change your code.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you made here is , you created the int array which must be Integer array because  `Arrays.asList().contains(Object o);` makes the input parameter also `Integer(Integer i)`. `int` is not an object `Integer` is the object. Hope it will work.

```
int[] arr = new int[bulkList.length];
```

change to:

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[bulkList.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the method as below to avoid complications:

```
public static boolean scan_bulkList(bulkBean[] bulkList, int i) {

        int[] arr = new int[bulkList.length];

        for(int x=0;x<bulkList.length;x++){
            arr[x] = bulkList[x].getInstallmentNo();
            if (bulkList[x].getInstallmentNo()==i) {
                return true;
            }                             
        }
   return false;

}
```